# Trouble connecting Mongoose to MongoDB Atlas cluster: Error EREFUSED

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mern

I'm currently working on a MERN stack project and facing an issue while attempting to connect my Mongoose to MongoDB Atlas and i already set IP address to access from anywhere so,i think it's not IP address whitelisted problem . Here's a snippet of the code I'm using for the connection:

```
import { connect, disconnect } from "mongoose";

async function connectToDatabase() {
  try {
    await connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error("Could not connect to MongoDb");
  }
}

async function disconnectFromDatabase() {
  try {
    await disconnect();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error("could not disconnect from Mongo");
  }
}

export { connectToDatabase, disconnectFromDatabase };
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Error: queryTxt EREFUSED cluster1.wcblrfc.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:275:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'EREFUSED',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'cluster1.wcblrfc.mongodb.net'
}
Error: Could not connect to MongoDb
```

What could be causing this 'EREFUSED' error, and how can I resolve it to successfully connect to my MongoDB Atlas cluster?

Comment: Host cluster1.wcblrfc.mongodb.net is not accessible from your machine where you are trying to connect with database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is connection problem I think.

You can try this code inside the try block:

```
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.mongo_user}:${process.env.mongo_password}@${process.env.mongo_DB_cluster}.mongodb.net/${your_DB}`;
await connect(uri);
```

Instead of this code:

```
await connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: thanks for the info broo, but it's still not connecting

Comment: @Codaswin Then don't _accept_ the answer. That signals to others that your problem is solved, and you won't attract more attention to your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Get the new connection String from mongodb Connect to cluster than replace with existing one[as per this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYVKb.png)